# How to override a method or assign a parameter value of a library class?

Tags: java, jar, overriding, shared-libraries

I'm developing a java application using a certain library(included using a jar file), i want to override a method exists on a class(abstract class) contained in that library, or even change a certain parameter value in it.
Is there is a way to do that?

Comment: You can try extending the class if it is allowed. This is what inheritance is all about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend the class from which you want to override the method.

```
public class ClassFromExtLib {
    public void foo(Object param) {
    }
}

public class MyClass extends ClassFromExtLib {
    @Override
    public void foo(Object param) {
         super.foo(param);
         //adding my own implementation...
    }
}
```

If you can't extend the class, use a wrapper class that can execute the method and then add your own logic to it.

```
public final class ClassFromExtLib {
    public void foo(Object param) {
    }
}

public class MyClass {
    //code to initialize the instance of the class ommited
    private ClassFromExtLib bar;

    public void foo(Object param) {
         bar.foo(param);
         //adding my own implementation...
    }

    public void foo(Object param, Object param2) {
         bar.foo(param);
         //adding my own implementation using param and param2...
    }
}
```

If you want to add/remove parameters from the method, then you can't do this by an overriding, that's an overloading. The second way would be the best for you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.  You can create a subclass which has the different behavior you want.

```
public class MyVersion extends JarVersion {
```

However if you change the signature, callers will typically ignore the change.
You can also use the delegate pattern.

```
public MyClass {
  JarClass delegate;

  public void myMethod(MyParm mp) {
    JarParm jp = makeJPfromMP(mp);
    extraStuff();
    delegate.originalMethod(jp);
    moreExtraStuff();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple,

Just create one another class that extends that class(assuming its extendable) for which you need modification

And then override the methods that you want to change.